# Evans Partial Differential Equations-Derivation of an equality

Tags: partial-differential-equations

When I am reading the chapter 2 of Evans, I met a problem in deriving the Kirchhoff's formula for wave equation in n=3. Evans set $\tilde{G}=rG$, where $G$ is the average of initial data $g$ on the sphere $\partial B(x,r)$. I have a problem to verify that $\tilde{G}_{rr}(0)=0$. Thank you very much.
[image: in the last line]

Comment: What have you tried? Compute the derivative in question with the chain rule and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. $\tilde{G}_r= G + rG_r$, thus $\tilde{G}_{rr} = 2G_r + rG_{rr}$. Consequently, $\tilde{G}_{rr}(0) = 2G_r(0)$. However, I don't know how to  verify $G_r(0)=0$, Could you give me some help?

Answer (score 1):

If the initial data $g$ is "localised", e.g., almost supported in a compact set (such as $C_c^2$ function, or a Schwartz function), you can use the argument in Theorem 2, chapter 2.2.2 in Evans' book.
We have $G(r)=\frac{1}{d\omega_dr^{d-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}g(y)dS_y$ with $\omega_d$ the volume of unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $y=x+rz$ where $z$ lies on the unit sphere, so by changing variables, we have $$G(r)=\frac{1}{d\omega_d}\int_{\partial B(0,1)} g(x+rz)dS_z.$$ Taking $\partial_r$, we have
$$G_r=\frac{1}{d\omega_d}\int_{\partial B(0,1)} \nabla g(x+rz)\cdot z\,\, dS_z.$$ Then we insert $z=r^{-1}(y-x)$ back to this equality and notice that $N:=\frac{y-x}{r}$ is exactly the unit outer normal vector to $\partial B(x,r)$ at the point $y\in \partial B(x,r)$. This time we have $$G_r=\frac{1}{d\omega_d r^{d-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} \frac{\partial g}{\partial n}(y)\,\, dS_y=\frac{r}{d\text{Vol}(B(x,r))}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} \frac{\partial g}{\partial n}(y)\,\, dS_y.$$ Finally, using divergence theorem, it becomes  $$G_r=\frac{r}{d}\frac{1}{\text{Vol}(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)} \Delta g(y)\,\, dy,$$ which decays to $0$ as $r\to 0_+$ if $\Delta g$ is Lebesgue integrable in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (using Lebesgue's differentiation theorem) (that's why I say the initial data is "localised".

Another thing you may need to notice is that, the 3D wave equation is reduced a 1D wave equation for $(t,r)$-variables in the half line $\{r>0\}$ which is expected to solve via reflection method (see page 69). The solution to 1D wave equation in the half line (with initial data $g,h$ and zero boundary value at $r=0$) is not $C^2$ unless you assume $g''(0)=0$ (See again the bottom of page 69). In fact, using reflection method, you get two different solutions for $r\gtrless t$ as in (10). The solution is $C^2$ iff the initial data satisfies certain compatibility conditions on the "boundary" (in particular, at the corner $\{t=0\}\times\{r=0\}$). We must have $\lim\limits_{t\to 0,r\to 0} (\partial_t ^2 u - \partial_r^2 u)=0$ which implies $g''(0)=\partial_t^2 u|_{t=0,x=0}=\partial_t^2 0=0$.

[I guess you might be an undergraduate student in China. If yes, you can find this argument about the compatibility conditions in Zhou Shulin's PDE book (page 158-160). If not, please omit my comment.]

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation. I will follow your suggestion to read the book by Shulin Zhou.

Comment: @corsair  u r welcome. I think the first part is already enough. When studying wave equation in $\mathbb{R}^d$, people usually assume the initial data to be localised to ensure the integrability. BTW, are you from USTC? It is rarely to see an undergrad student (except in USTC) asks Evans PDE problem and mathematical analysis problems at the same time.